# python read a lot files and write information into a single txt

Tags: python, file, io

I have a folder that contains 30911 html files. I want to write all file names and some desired information (using beautifulsoup) into a txt file and each file name will occupy a line.

```
file1.html
file2.html
file3.html
..
file30911.html
```

The problem I encounter is that sometimes it has an error because the files' format is not consistent.

So, I want still keep the complete information while it stopped. Then when I re-run the code, it will start from wherever it stopped and add the left information into the file.
Can anyone help to add this purpose into my code?

My code:

```
import re, os, bs4, glob
path = 'C:/output/' #all the 30911 html files
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.html')):
    #I will not post beautifulsoup's code to save space here.
    try:
        #some beautifulsoup code to find tags
    except:
        indexFile = open('C:/output1/' + 'index.txt', 'a+')
        indexFile.write(os.path.basename(filename) + ', ' + title.get_text(strip=True) + 'no participants')
    else:
        indexFile = open('C:/output1/' + 'index.txt', 'a+')
        indexFile.write(os.path.basename(filename) + ', ' + title.get_text(strip=True) + ', '+ parti_names)
        indexFile.close()
```

Comment: Are these files unchanging? Or is there a chance that files will be modified, added, or deleted?

Comment: what happens when you hit an inconsistency? Exception? Can you catch it and carry on with the next file? Also how many inconsistencies are there? Just a few or a lot, can you not write your bs code in a way that is not affected by these? It's very difficult to suggest a solution as you have explained your problem at a high level, but have provided no specifics.

Comment: @AustinHastings Files unchanged. I output the index.txt to another folder though

Comment: the exception block is for catch no find the desired content atm @PaulRooney I'm not sure how many are there since I did not check all 30911 files...

Comment: Or is it better to move the completed html files to other folder so next time I re-run the code, it will only conduct the rest files

Comment: Well what will you do different the second time? You catch all exceptions in your code, have you tried putting traces in that block to see if its ever reached? Watch also you don't close your files in the except block, if you have a lot of files processed in that block you may run out of file handles. It would be better to open the file once before the glob call, use `with` and you don't have to worry about closing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the existing 'C:/output1/index.txt' file into a list and check new lines against it before appending the line.

```
existing_files = []

with open('C:/output1/index.txt') as infile:
    for item in infile:
        existing_files.append(item)
    #do parsing here
    #then check before you append to the file
    if file_to_write not in existing_files:
        #append the file
```